# Universal Apps using Unity & Prism

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, win-universal-app

I am learning the whole new Universal Apps creation together with Prism and Unity, but I got a few questions I am not sure about:

I have the following simple data object:

```
public class Customer : IEditableObject, IEquatable<Customer>
{
    private Customer backup;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        this.backup = this.MemberwiseClone() as Customer;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        this.Name = this.backup.Name;
        this.Surname = this.backup.Surname;
        this.DateOfBirth = this.backup.DateOfBirth;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        this.backup = this.MemberwiseClone() as Customer;
    }

    public bool WasChangeMade()
    {
        if (this.Equals(backup))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public bool Equals(Customer other)
    {
        return this.Name == other.Name &&
            this.Surname == other.Surname &&
            this.DateOfBirth == other.DateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Under my Main Page I have a simple `ListBox`, where I show collection of these Customers. Everything good so far.

Afterwards, when under my `ListBox` user selects any one of these `Customer`, then he can click Edit Settings button and edit properties of this selected Customer. It is a simple command:

```
        cmd_EditCustomer = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            _navigationService.Navigate(App.Experiences.Detail.ToString(), SelectedCustomer);
        });
```

Which simply navigates to a new page (detail page, where user can do the changes) and the argument I pass here is the Selected `Customer`.

My DetailPage View Model looks like following:

```
public class DetailPageViewModel : ViewModel, Interfaces.IDetailPageViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand cmd_SaveChanges { get; set; }
    public Customer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }

    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    public DetailPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,
        IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        InitializeCommands();
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(object navigationParameter, NavigationMode navigationMode, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
    {
        this.SelectedCustomer = navigationParameter as Customer;
        this.SelectedCustomer?.BeginEdit();
    }

    private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        cmd_SaveChanges = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            SelectedCustomer?.EndEdit();
            _dialogService.Show("Changes Saved!");
            _navigationService.Navigate(App.Experiences.Main.ToString(), null);
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a very simple application, which I only use for learning purposes. Here are my questions:

**1)** Is it good to pass Selected Customer in such a way as I did? (in the parameter of the `INavigationService`), or should I implement other logic?

**2)** When user makes a change to the Selected Customer and clicks Save Changes (the only command you can see there), it does not update the original Customer (from my original collection). How is this possible? How to achieve, that my Customer will be updated? Should I create `PubSubEvent` for this?

**EDIT:**

I have managed to locate the error - when user navigates back to `MainPage`, my `MainPageViewModel` is re-initializes, which re-populates collection of items. The question now is - how can I keep `MainWindowViewModel` alive thorough the applications life?

Answer (score 1):

Re-populates collection of items from **what**?

You just need to save a new values, for example if you populate your customers from DB you have to call DB and save changes before navigate back etc, so after that when MainPageViewModel would be re-initializes you'll get your changes and changes performed by another users.

Comment: Currently I am reading a values from a simple XML file. I have done some research and based on what I have found, I should use something like repository patterns. Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertJ. there is not one simple answer, some people will tell you to use repository pattern, others will tell the opposite. It comes down, to how big the application you writing is and what frameworks you use. For example entity framework 7 which will support uwp has repository pattern implemented in it, however some people still prefer to have their own implementation over the one provided in that framework.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out that this was not a good way how to hold data in your application.

Based on what I have read, I should have implemented Repository Strategy, which is only referenced in a ViewModel such as:

```
public MainPageViewModel(IDataRepository dataRepository, INavigationService navService, ...){etc.}
```

Example of a simplified interface:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    List<string> GetListOfStrings();
    string GetUserEnteredData();
    void SetUserEnteredData(string data);
}
```

This is how you initialize it in `UnityContainer`:

```
_container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();
```

You can read more from Patterns & Practices team in here:
https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/